# How to permanently add CSS to some pages using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css

How to permanently add CSS to some pages using Firefox?

Say, I want to change the font or background of a page I frequent using Firefox.

How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Greasemonkey is a good option..

Answer (score 8):

There's a great extension called [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) that does exactly what you're looking for. It allows you to add custom CSS to the pages you visit.

Answer (score 5):

You can add custom CSS rules to a `chrome/userContent.css` file in your Firefox profile folder.

- [Open your profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Finding_the_profile_folder)
- Create the "chrome" directory if it doesn't exist
- Create the "chrome/userContent.css" file

Example:

```css
/* For any page */
body { margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red !important; }

/* Or only for google.com */
@-moz-document domain(google.com) {
    body { margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red !important; }
}
```

Comment: Firefox restart needed for every change. Also, you can also use regular expressions to match an URL, for example: `@-moz-document regex(".*\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$")`. Which I used to make the image viewer of Firefox zoom in without blurring pixels (`img{image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;image-rendering: pixelated;}`).

Comment: I did this now in 2019, still works when you don't want to find and install an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `chrome/userContent.css` in your profile folder but as of Firefox 69 and newer, you have to manually set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` in `about:config` to work.